# how to change Mega Menu's submenu font-size in DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke-6

I am just starting out to learn how to implement a DotNetNuke website. I have installed everything and got the starter-site up and running and have started off by attempting to change a few bits and pieces to get a feel of how it works.

I've added a menu item to the existing menu (Admin --> Page Management --> Add Page (and then added 8 sub-pages underneath)

Under the Appearance of the new menu item I've given it a Skin of "Host: DarkKnight - 3-Column-Mega-Menu"

The sub-pages or submenu now appears on mouse-over no problem, however the font-size of the submenu items is way to big and I cannot for the life of me figure out where / how to change this.

I am using the latest download of DNN (which I think is version 6)

Appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the `dnnmega.css` file in `/portal/Portals/_default/Skins/DarkKnight/DNNMega.`

in this line change `font-size` value:

```
ul.dnnmega li.category a span{display:block;font-size:18px;color:#686868;border-bottom:1px solid #e5e4e4;margin:0 14px 0 18px;padding:0;}
```

You test other modifies and see.
For change the number of coloumns (if there are more submenus) and other behaviours you need to edit the `jquery.dnnmega.debug.js` ( and `jquery.dnnmega.js` )